# I don't understand why my function doesn't happen

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am trying to write a typing challenge game where the player has to type a word as fast as possible within the time limit. At the end of the `game()` function it is supposed to execute the `round1()` function when the timer gets to `0`. However, nothing happens and it just stays on the number `1`. Any ideas what is causing this behavior?

This is the code I am using:

```
import random
import time
global timer
timer = 20
global counting
counting = 10
global rounds
rounds = 0
def menu():
    print ("Main Menu\nType in 'start' to begin the typing challenge")
    start = input()
    if start == "start":
        game()
    else:
        menu()
def game():
    global counting
    choices = ["snazzy", "pizzas", "sizzle", "jackal"]   
    global word
    word = (random.choice(choices))
    print ("The word you must type is", word)
    print ("You will be timed on how long it takes you to type the word.")
    print ("Each round you will have a slightly smaller amount of time to type the word")
    time.sleep(10)
    print ("Starting in...")
    for count in range(10):
        print (counting)
        time.sleep(1)
        counting -=1  
    round1()
def round1():
    useless = 100
    global rounds
    global word
    global timer
    while useless > 1:
        for count in range(20):
            time.sleep(1)
            timer -=1
    print ("Type", word)
    attempt = input()
    if attempt == word and timer > 0:
        rounds = rounds+1
        round2()
    else:
        lose()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting into the function `round1`, but once you are there, you are caught in an infinite loop because the variable `useless` will never change.

Even if you take out the `while` loop, you will never be able to win because you do not take input in until after the timer has already run out.

Comment: There is no need for concurrency here it's simple flow game

Comment: True, no need for concurrency. I did not think about just running a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from round 1 on:

```
def round1():
    import sys, select
    global rounds
    global word
    global timer
    print ("Type", word)
    input, out, error = select.select( [sys.stdin], [], [], timer)
    if (input):
        attempt = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
        if attempt == word:
            rounds = rounds+1
            round2()
        else:
            lose()
    else:
        lose()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu()
```

Note that, as-is, it will fail with a `NameError` since you don't have a `round2()` function defined. A better solution would be to generalize your function, with something like `round_x(number, word, time_to_answer)`; That way you can reuse the same code and don't have to import globals.

Comment: Note, this will not work as-is on Windows, but it works just fine on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing a bit with your game you're doing too many overhead and mistakes 
there so I just changed it's structure to simplify:

```
import random
import time
current_milli_time = lambda:int(time.time() * 1000)
timer = 20 #suppose user has 20 secs to enter a word
counting = 10
requested_word = ""
choices = ["snazzy", "pizzas", "sizzle", "jackal"]   
rounds = 0
def menu():
    print ("Main Menu\nType in 'start' to begin the typing challenge")
    game() if input().lower() == "start" else menu()
#There is no need to split game and round but I didn't want to mess with
#your program structure too much
def game():
    global requested_word
    try:
        requested_word = (random.choice(choices))
        choices.remove(requested_word)
    except IndexError:
        print "Game is finished"
        return
    print ("The word you must type is", requested_word)
    print ("You will be timed on how long it takes you to type the word.")
    print ("Each round you will have a slightly smaller amount of time to type the word")
    print ("Starting typing in in...")
    for count in range(10,-1,-1):
        print (count)
        time.sleep(1)
    round()
def round():
    global timer
    start = current_milli_time()
    word = input("Enter word -> ")
    stop = current_milli_time()
    time_delta = stop-start #this is in milliseconds
    if time_delta< timer*1000 and word == requested_word :
        timer = timer-5 #lower the time to enter a word
        game()
    else:
        print("Game OVER")
menu()
```

When prompt 'Enter word ->' appears the user has all the time he wants to enter a word, but after it time_delta is calculated and if it passes your limit, it's game over for him.